# How to skip a level with Unity's PlayerPrefs?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

everyone.

I've been at this for some time now. Basically, I am working on a mobile game and I want to set up my ad button to skip a level if someone presses it. Now it keeps track of where I left off, but it won't reset when I press the Start Over button and skip the level I just left before the attempts to restart.

I have attempted to use two different functions to work this- but first, here is the focus and issue- the int "sceneNo" and the StartOver function. I used PlayerPrefs to set up sceneNo. up.

```
sceneNo = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

And, here's the code for StartOver.

```
public void StartOver()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("level");
    sceneNo = (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

As for the the two different functions I've tried to reset the game...

```
public void SkipMe()
{

    sceneNo = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level", sceneNo));
}
```

And the current one...

```
public void SkipAdFunction()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNo);
    Answer.text = "";
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", sceneNo + 1);
    sceneNo = (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

}
```

Lastly, here's the rest of the script to do this.

```
void HandleShowResult(ShowResult result) { if (result == ShowResult.Finished) { Playable.GetComponent<LoadScene>().SkipMe();
```

Both of these scripts do the same thing.
Any and all help would be appreciated on how to resolve the issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) you can edit your question, 2) don't use playerprefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **StartOver()** you are mentioning this

```
 PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("level");
```

But in **SkipMe(), SkipAdFunction()** you wrote this

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", sceneNo + 1);
```

See the **Level**, you are mentioning the different keys, keys are case sensitive, So change it

Comment: Oh my gosh. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks. However, now the script skips two levels.

Comment: No problem ...Happy coding